# dplyr:separate auto name "into"-columns based on "col"

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Suppose I have a dataframe:

```
require(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(COL1 = c("a1 a2 a3", "b1 b2 b3", "c1 c2 c3"), 
                 COL2 = c("x", "y", "z"),
                 COL3 = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

I want the result to be

```
  COL1_1 COL1_2 COL1_3 COL2 COL3
1     a1     a2     a3    x    1
2     b1     b2     b3    y    2
3     c1     c2     c3    z    3
```

What I have right now to do so is

```
df %>%
  separate(col = COL1, sep = " ", into = c("COL1_1", "COL1_2", "COL1_3"))
```

**Is there a way to automate the `into` part of the expression?**

Something like that uses the original column name `COL1` and concatenates that with a subscript `_i` with `i` being the the "subcolumn". The approach needs to adapt automatically to different numbers of "subcolumns", e.g. `a1, a2, a3,..., an`.

Comment: We can do this with `read.table` i.e.  `cbind(read.table(text=as.character(df$COL1)), df)`

Comment: `separate(df, col = COL1, into = paste0("COL1_", 1:3))`?

Comment: Thanks  for the replies ! akrun: problem with this proposal is that this keeps the original column and does not transmute it. david: Problem is I still have to specify the `3` and the original column name `COL1_` by hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be automated with `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
 cSplit(df, 'COL1', ' ')
```